# Secure copy with parent directory

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I have a set of files on a remote server structured like this:

```
~/dir_1/file
~/dir_2/file
~/dir_3/file
...
~/dir_N/file
```

I would like to copy these files to my local computer and create their *immediate* parent directories. I tried this in bash but it does not work:

```
scp name@remote.server:~/dir_*/file ./
```

Would appreciate any help. I am using Mac OSX.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not a programming question. Probably Linux & Unix or SuperUser.

Comment: Try reading the man page for rsync. I believe some combination of options will do what you want, but too many details are missing from your question to create an exact answer.

Comment: So, `dir_1` contains many other files & you want to copy only one file named `file` AND maintain the directory structure? If so, use `rsync` as suggested by Zan Lynx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *globbing* on remote server to match `file` only in the subdirs + *tar* to create the the complete hierarchy

```
ssh name@remote-server "tar cf - dir_*/file"|tar xf -
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking [Rsync manual](http://ss64.com/osx/rsync.html), and supposing there's no missed things in your question, you have to do:

```
rsync -av name@remote.server:~/dir_* .
```

Quoting manual:

> rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp
>
> This would recursively transfer all files from the directory src/bar
>   on  the  machine  foo  into  the /data/tmp/bar  directory  on  the 
>   local  machine. The files are transferred in "archive" mode, which
>   ensures that symbolic links, devices, attributes, permissions,
>   ownerships, etc. are preserved in  the transfer.   Additionally, 
>   compression will be used to reduce the size of data portions of the
>   trans-fer. transfer.

Options may differ deppending on your SO version, check `man rsync`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I did not want to copy the entire directories. When I tried `~/dir_*/file` instead, it just kept overwriting the same file.